# Read contents of express route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

does anyone know of a way I can read the contents of my express route? For example, suppose I have a route like:

```
router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  let postBody = {
    firstName: {
      required: true,
      description: "First Name"
    },
    lastName: {
      required: true,
      description: "Last Name"
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      description: "Your email"
    }
  }

  res.json({
    msg: "Success"
  })

})
```

My objective is to read the contents of `postBody` for each route when the app starts.

My `app.js`:

```
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()
const app = express()


app._router.stack.forEach(middleware => {
  if (middleware.handle && middleware.handle.stack) {
     middleware.handle.stack.forEach(route => {
       console.log(route)
     })
  }
})

app.use(router)
```

Using the above code, I can print out all of my routes. However, I am looking to print out the `postBody` of each route when the app starts. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Would you be open to refactoring your code, so that your `postBody`s were included outside the routes? They would still be referenced inside the routes. This would let you easily get the contents on app load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place that you have kept postBody variable is only executed when those routes are hit. To read them outside of those call backs you should be able to pass them into a common module. In my sample below I call it "postBodies". Every route passes its postBody into this module and as the last entry in the bottom of your main app.js file I call readAll() to print out all the internally stored postBody values up to that point.

```
const postBodies = require("./postBodies.js")

router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  let postBody = {
    firstName: {
      required: true,
      description: "First Name"
    },
    lastName: {
      required: true,
      description: "Last Name"
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      description: "Your email"
    }
  }
  postBodies.update(postBody)


  res.json({
    msg: "Success"
  })

})
```

postBodies.js

```
var bodies[]

module.exports.update = function(x){
  bodies.push(x)
}

module.exports.readAll = function(){
  bodies.forEach(function(x){
   console.log(x)
  }
}
```

app.js or index.js

At the very bottom after all your route calls.

```
postBodies.readAll()
```